# AutoIt assembly code to print a message

Tags: assembly, autoit

I'm making a program to show `hello world` using AutoIt. The assembly code was used in examples for other languages but not AutoIt. The code is:

```
char code[] =
"\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00"
"\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00"
"\xb9\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"\xba\x0f\x00\x00\x00"
"\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00"
"\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00"
"\x00\x00\xcd\x80";
```

I will try using AutoIt so:

```
$pt = DLLStructCreate("byte[" & BinaryLen($YourShellcode) & "]")

DllStructSetData($pt, 1, $YourShellcode)

$y=DllStructGetPtr($pt)

_WinAPI_CallWindowProc($y, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

But I am not sure how to include this assembly code to print `hello world`. How to do it? Only a small example of `hello world` using asm and AutoIt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to do this?

```
#include <WinAPI.au3>
Global $YourShellcode = "0xb804000000bb01000000b900000000ba0f000000cd80b801000000bb00000000cd80"

$pt = DLLStructCreate("byte[" & BinaryLen($YourShellcode) & "]")

DllStructSetData($pt, 1, $YourShellcode)

$y=DllStructGetPtr($pt)

_WinAPI_CallWindowProc($y, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```